# How do I get a main rails application to use an engines route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am creating my first rails engine to handle remote authentication in a rails 4 application. I am using http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html as my guide for helping me with this.

I have created a sessions controller inside the engine which I will be used to handle the authentication logic but I am having a hard time getting my main application to route to the engine to prompt for authentication.

My engines routes file has:

```
resources :sessions only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

If I run rake routes, I can see that my routes are there. But I am not sure how to access them. for instance:

```
auth_test$ rake routes
Prefix Verb URI Pattern            Controller#Action
tests_index GET  /tests/index(.:format) tests#index
my_engine      /my_engine        MyEngine::Engine
root GET  /                      tests#index

Routes for MyEngine::Engine:
sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)     my_engine/sessions#create
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format) my_engine/sessions#new
session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format) my_engine/sessions#destroy
```

I tried using things in the normal ways such as new_session_path but that doesn't appear to work. I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_session_path' for #<TestsController:0x007fba02150c20>
```

How would I specify this route so that my main application knows to use the routes from my engine and not its main routes?

Comment: have you mounted your engine on your `config/routes.rb` file?

Comment: @xlembouras yes, I did mount it using mount MyEngine::Engine, at: "/my_engine". I assumed without this, they wouldn't show up when I ran rake routes though I did not verify that.

Answer (score 1):

From the app to the engine:

```
<%= link_to "Sessions", my_engine.new_session_path %>
```

From the engine to the app

```
<%= link_to "Test Index", main_app.tests_index_path %>
```